# Which version of Java is supported by plexus-compiler-eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

For consistency between dev and prod environment I would prefer to use the same compiler.  Since I develop using Eclipse, Theia (Gitpod) and VSCode that all use Eclipse-derived Java tooling, I would prefer to use ECJ.

In the past, I used ECJ via Maven, using the plexus-compiler-eclipse plugin.  Is there a place where I can find which Java version is supported by a given version of the plugin?  For example, what version would this give me?

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.plexus/plexus-compiler-eclipse -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
    <artifactId>plexus-compiler-eclipse</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Why don't you ask the developers of the software? They're probably more likely to have a correct answer quickly.

Comment: They do not answer requests.